# Trobleshooting monitor acer AL 1916W

Tags: display

My monitor acer AL 1916W when I put it on it blinks green and yellow while display is black. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try a different monitor, or a different computer with the same monitor. Also, try a different cable.

Answer (score 0):

Those monitors have a reputation for failing capacitors.  Try it on a different computer first, but if that doesn't work it's probably dead.

If you've got a soldering iron, you can probably resurrect it cheaply by replacing the affected capacitors. Have a look at these instructions:

http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f25/acer-monitor-is-blank-and-power-light-flashing-green-318760.html#post2046114